# Stopping Dwarf Fortress from auto-pausing

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is it possible to prevent DF from pausing every time something comes up (liking hitting gold or whatever). The reason is that I am doing extensive mining and I want to leave the process unattended till it is over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Navigate to Dwarf Fortress / Data / Init.

You should be in a folder with at least 7 files. The one you are looking for is "ANNOUNCEMENTS". This controls much of the announcement behavior. Others, such as the seasonal pausing, can be found in the init and d_init files.

Simply alter the files in question with a text editor (the files themselves are pretty well documented as to how to alter them) to reach your desired state of affairs.